# Authentication error using cloudflare api

Tags: api, curl, cloudflare

I repeatedly received an authentication error just like [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/api-dns-records-error-10000-authentication-error/298291) (not me) when using the Cloudflare api.

```
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<ZONEID>/dns_records?type=A&name=<DOMAIN>&content=127.0.0.1&proxied=undefined&page=1&per_page=20&order=type&direction=desc&match=all" \
 -H "X-Auth-Email: <EMAIL>" \
 -H "X-Auth-Key: <APITOKEN>" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

```
 {“success”:false,“errors”:[{“code”:10000,“message”:“Authentication error”}]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting that exact same error message, and I found out that I was using the **API Token** instead of the **API Key** in the `X-Auth-Key` parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Difference between the API Token and the API Key can be found here: https://api.cloudflare.com/#getting-started-requests

Comment: Just in case someone didn't understand the answer, you have to use the Global API Key. You can find it at `My Profile > API Tokens`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way that seems to work is to use the user token instead of the zone one.

> `curl -XPOST -H 'X-Auth-Key:` **TOKEN**`' -H 'X-auth-email:` **EMAIL**`' -H \"Content-type: application/json\" -d '{\"type\":\"CNAME\",\"name\":\"hi\",\"content\":\"example.com\",\"proxied\":true}' 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/`**ZONE_ID**`/dns_records'`